# How to solve create_order_error {err: 'Error: TOKEN_FAILURE\n paypal

Tags: javascript, token, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I am doing a smart button paypal checkout. The first action create a new subscription works correctly and return a json with all the necessary information about the subscription, but then instead of execute onApprove function, i get this error on my console.

[image]

Here is my js code:

```
    <script>
        paypal.Buttons({
            locale: 'it_IT',
            style: {
                layout: 'horizontal',
                size: 'responsive',
                color: 'gold',
                shape: 'pill',
                tagline: false
            },
            createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
                return fetch('/?action=URL_ACTION', {
                    method: 'post',
                    headers: {
                        'content-type': 'application/json'
                    }
                }).then(function(res) {

                    return res.json();
                }).then(function(orderData) {

                    return orderData.id;
                });
            },
            onApprove: function(data, actions) {


                $.post('/?action=URL_SECOND_ACTION',{'data':data});


            },
            onError: function (err) {

                console.log(err);
            }
          }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    </script>
```

Comment: This had been reported here as well, fingers crossed we get more details soon:

https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout-components/issues/2026